# Unable to convert datetime yyyyMMdd to ddMMyyyy for SAP matrix

Tags: c#

I am developing an SAP addon that reads excel sheets and then loads the information into a matrix. A user can edit the information on the matrix and then save the data to the SAP database.

The date columns on the Excel sheet, e.g. `DocDate`, are all in the format `yyyyMMdd` e.g. `20120813`.

I use the following code to parse the dates from the date columns to the SAP format of `ddMMyyyy`:

```
//Method to get date from string

private DateTime GetDateFromString(string dateString)
{

string format = "yyyyMMdd";

DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

return d;
}
```

However, when the data appears on my Matrix, it is in the format `yyMMdd` on the date matrix columns. I try to convert to a valid SAP date format by using:

```
_oPCH.DocDate = GetDateFromString(docDate.Value);
```

I get the error

> date string is not in the correct format

Applying breakpoints to my code, I get the formats I'm trying to parse as `12.08.13`.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: is `_oPCH.DocDate` really expecting a `DateTime` ?

Comment: Its a SAP business object and it expects a DateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior may altered by applying a new culture to the current thread (UI or simple depending on your context).

The new culture should implement the `DateTimeFormat` you desire, you will have to test out all fields in your case.

Instead of "en-US" you can use "" as in empty string for invariant culture, your choice.

```
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(now);
    CultureInfo sapCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
    sapCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "ddMMyyyy";
    //sapCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = sapCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + " HH-mm-ss";
    sapCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH-mm-ss";
    //sapCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH-mm-ss";
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = sapCulture;
    //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = sapCulture;
    Console.WriteLine(now);
```

For more format specifications see [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Alexandru Lache. I did not understand what was happening but after some time I have figured it out with your help.